# precedence of class of local .java file or imported class from package in java?

Tags: java, package

one class using another class which is parallel to it(i.e. .java file existing in same folder as in that class) and it is also getting the same class from another package by importing to that class from another folder,
priority should be given local class i.e. .java existing in same folder but it is running from
pacakage from another folder ? 
code is mentioned below:

\\ .java file in same folder\\

```
public class Temp1
{
public void show()
    {
    System.out.println("show from local");
    }
public static void main()
    {
    Temp1 t1=new Temp1();
    t1.show();
    }
}
```

\\.java file having same class in diff. folder \\

```
public class Temp1
{
public void show()
    {
    System.out.println("show from global");
    }
public static void main()
    {
    Temp1 t1=new Temp1();
    t1.show();
    }
}
```

//here is the main class that i am running//

```
 package p2;
 import p1.*;
 class Temp2
 {
    public static void main(String... s)
    {
    Temp1 t1=new Temp1();
    t1.show();
    }
  }
```

Help me out ...

Comment: Please pay more attention to the formatting of code in your post. Use spaces instead of tabs to indent.

Comment: Is this a question or a post ?

Comment: Welp... what did you find out when you ran it?

Comment: Decompile your class with `javap`. It's a wealth of information.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `Temp1` and the `mainClass` are in `package2` and you compile the main class then obviously the `Temp1` of the same package will be compile and called.

but if `Temp1` is in `package1` and the other `Temp1` in in `package3` then in that case that specific class will be called whomever you add it to the `classpath` while compiling the `mainClass`

Comment: That is obvious but i am talking about scenario when Temp1 is in package1 which i am importing to main class (and its classpath has been set) and another Temp1 in same folder as in main class so that it is not needed to be import in main class thus precedence should be given to this Temp1 class and it should be compiled that and run but it is not working in that way and compiling Temp1 class imported from package1.